# Kivy - Changing Row height of FloatLayout within GridLayout with implemented ScrollView

Tags: python, kivy, scrollview, row-height

I'm trying to create a Scrollview with two columns that has 4-5 Icons+Subscripts under them in each "category" separated by a simple title. I have all of the ImageButtons lines up with the subscript of each Image button with a FloatLayout, and all of this is inside of a GridLayout (with one column).

My question is how do I change the Height of the first row (main Title), and rows which include the titles of each category -Secondary smaller font titles of each categroy, (the height of rows which include the Buttons + corresponding subscript are perfect).

As of now, to get my scrollview to work, I have to have a row_default_height value, otherwise all my rows are stacked...
And since if all rows are the same height by default, this leaves a lot of empty space taken up by what I want to be a smaller title.

Here's what I've got so far:

'''

:

```
FloatLayout:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex("#69B3F2")
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

    ScrollView:
        pos_hint: {"top": 1,"right":1}
        size_hint: 1,1


        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            row_default_height: '100dp'
            spacing: 10,10
            row_force_default: False


            FloatLayout:
                

                Label:

                    
                    font_color:
                        utils.get_color_from_hex("#424FFF")
                    id: general_relativity_label
                    font_size: 25
                    font_name: "Rubik-Bold.ttf"
                    text: "Calculator (by Gleb)"
                    pos_hint: {"top": 0.9, "left": 1}
                    markup: True



            FloatLayout:

                pos_hint: {"top": 0.9,"right":1}
                size_hint: 1,0.225
                

                ImageButton:
                    pos_hint: {"top": 0.8, "right":.85}
                    size_hint: 0.2, 0.7
                    source: "Icons4/014-gravity.png"
                    on_release:
                        app.change_screen("kinematics_screen", direction='right', mode='push')

                ImageButton:
                    pos_hint: {"top": 0.8, "right": 0.35}
                    size_hint: 0.2, 0.7
                    source: "Icons4/019-relativity.png"
                    on_release:
                        app.change_screen("relativity_screen", direction='right', mode='push')

                Label:
                    pos_hint: {"top": 0.1, "right": .85}
                    size_hint: .2,0.15
                    font_color:
                        utils.get_color_from_hex("#425FFF")
                    font_size: 18
                    text: "Kinematics"
                    markup: True

                Label:
                    pos_hint: {"top": 0.1,"right": 0.35}
                    size_hint: .2,0.15
                    font_color:
                        utils.get_color_from_hex("#425FFF")
                    font_size: 18
                    text: "Relativity"
                    markup: True

            FloatLayout:

                pos_hint: {"top": 0.675, "left":1}
                size_hint: 1,0.225
                #Quantum Tunneling, Energy of H atom

                ImageButton:
                    pos_hint: {"top":0.8,"right":.85}
                    size_hint: .2,.7
                    source: "Icons4/049-atom.png"
                    on_release:
                        app.change_screen("quantum_screen", direction='right', mode='push')

                ImageButton:
                    pos_hint: {"top": 0.8, "right":0.35}
                    size_hint: .2,.7
                    source: "Icons4/046-transverse wave.png"
                    on_release:
                        print("Waves")


                Label:
                    pos_hint: {"top": 0.1,"right":.85}
                    size_hint: .2,.15
                    font_color:
                        utils.get_color_from_hex("#425FFF")
                    font_size: 18
                    text: "Quantum"
                    markup: True

                Label:
                    pos_hint: {"top": 0.1,"right":.35}
                    size_hint: .2,.15
                    font_color:
                        utils.get_color_from_hex("#425FFF")
                    font_size: 18
                    text: "Waves"
                    markup: True

            FloatLayout:

                pos_hint: {"top": 0.450,"left":1}
                size_hint: 1,.225
               

                ImageButton:
                    pos_hint: {"top": 0.8,"right":.85}
                    size_hint: .2,.7
                    source: "Icons4/034-orbit.png"
                    on_release:
                        print("Astronomy")

                ImageButton:
                    pos_hint: {"top": 0.8,"right":.35}
                    size_hint: .2,.7
                    source: "Icons4/018-clamp.png"
                    on_release:
                        print("Forces")

                Label:
                    pos_hint: {"top": 0.1,"right":.85}
                    size_hint: .2,.15
                    font_color:
                        utils.get_color_from_hex("#425FFF")
                    font_size: 18
                    text: "Astro"

                Label:
                    pos_hint: {"top": 0.1,"right":.35}
                    size_hint: .2,.15
                    font_color:
                        utils.get_color_from_hex("#425FFF")
                    font_size: 18
                    text: "Forces"

            FloatLayout:

                pos_hint: {"top": 0.675, "left":1}
                size_hint: 1,0.225
                

                ImageButton:
                    pos_hint: {"top":0.8,"right":.85}
                    size_hint: .2,.7
                    source: "Icons4/049-atom.png"
                    on_release:
                        app.change_screen("quantum_screen", direction='right', mode='push')

                ImageButton:
                    pos_hint: {"top": 0.8, "right":0.35}
                    size_hint: .2,.7
                    source: "Icons4/046-transverse wave.png"
                    on_release:
                        print("Waves")


                Label:
                    pos_hint: {"top": 0.1,"right":.85}
                    size_hint: .2,.15
                    font_color:
                        utils.get_color_from_hex("#425FFF")
                    font_size: 18
                    text: "Quantum"
                    markup: True

                Label:
                    pos_hint: {"top": 0.1,"right":.35}
                    size_hint: .2,.15
                    font_color:
                        utils.get_color_from_hex("#425FFF")
                    font_size: 18
                    text: "Waves"
                    markup: True

            FloatLayout:
                pos_hint: {"top": 0.450,"left":1}
                size_hint: 1,.225
                

                ImageButton:
                    pos_hint: {"top": 0.8,"right":.85}
                    size_hint: .2,.7
                    source: "Icons4/034-orbit.png"
                    on_release:
                        print("Astronomy")

                ImageButton:
                    pos_hint: {"top": 0.8,"right":.35}
                    size_hint: .2,.7
                    source: "Icons4/018-clamp.png"
                    on_release:
                        print("Forces")

                Label:
                    pos_hint: {"top": 0.1,"right":.85}
                    size_hint: .2,.15
                    font_color:
                        utils.get_color_from_hex("#425FFF")
                    font_size: 18
                    text: "Astro"

                Label:
                    pos_hint: {"top": 0.1,"right":.35}
                    size_hint: .2,.15
                    font_color:
                        utils.get_color_from_hex("#425FFF")
                    font_size: 18
                    text: "Forces"
```

'''

Thanks in advance!
p.s -> pretty new to kivy, but I can confidently say I've googled a ton and couldn't come up with a solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a series of `BoxLayouts` instead of one `GridLayout`, then the rows do not have to be the same height.  Here is a modified version of your `kv` that does that:

```
#:import utils kivy.utils
#:set ImageButtonHeight 150

<ImageButton>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: ImageButtonHeight
    
<MyLabel@Label>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.texture_size[1]
    font_color:
        utils.get_color_from_hex("#425FFF")
    font_size: 18
    markup: True

FloatLayout:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex("#69B3F2")
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

    ScrollView:

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            spacing: 10,10

            Label:
                font_color:
                    utils.get_color_from_hex("#424FFF")
                id: general_relativity_label
                font_size: 25
                font_name: "Rubik-Bold.ttf"
                text: "Calculator (by Gleb)"
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                markup: True

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    ImageButton:
                        source: "Icons4/014-gravity.png"
                        on_release:
                            app.change_screen("kinematics_screen", direction='right', mode='push')
    
                    ImageButton:
                        source: "Icons4/019-relativity.png"
                        on_release:
                            app.change_screen("relativity_screen", direction='right', mode='push')
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    MyLabel:
                        text: "Kinematics"
    
                    MyLabel:
                        text: "Relativity"

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint: 1,None
                height: self.minimum_height
                #Quantum Tunneling, Energy of H atom

                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    ImageButton:
                        source: "Icons4/049-atom.png"
                        on_release:
                            app.change_screen("quantum_screen", direction='right', mode='push')
    
                    ImageButton:
                        source: "Icons4/046-transverse wave.png"
                        on_release:
                            print("Waves")


                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    MyLabel:
                        text: "Quantum"
    
                    MyLabel:
                        text: "Waves"

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
               
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    ImageButton:
                        source: "Icons4/034-orbit.png"
                        on_release:
                            print("Astronomy")
    
                    ImageButton:
                        source: "Icons4/018-clamp.png"
                        on_release:
                            print("Forces")

                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    MyLabel:
                        text: "Astro"
    
                    MyLabel:
                        text: "Forces"

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    ImageButton:
                        source: "Icons4/049-atom.png"
                        on_release:
                            app.change_screen("quantum_screen", direction='right', mode='push')
    
                    ImageButton:
                        source: "Icons4/046-transverse wave.png"
                        on_release:
                            print("Waves")

                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    MyLabel:
                        text: "Quantum"
    
                    MyLabel:
                        text: "Waves"

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                
                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    ImageButton:
                        source: "Icons4/034-orbit.png"
                        on_release:
                            print("Astronomy")
    
                    ImageButton:
                        source: "Icons4/018-clamp.png"
                        on_release:
                            print("Forces")

                BoxLayout:
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.minimum_height
                    MyLabel:
                        text: "Astro"
    
                    MyLabel:
                        text: "Forces"
```

When using `minimum_height` for a `BoxLayout`, you must make sure that the height of each child is well defined. To do that (as well as simplifying the `kv`), I created rules for the `ImageButton` and a `MyLabel` class that is used in place of most of the `Labels` in the `kv`.

The general structure of the above code is like this:

```
ScrollView:
    BoxLayout:  # this is the top level BoxLayout, each child is a row
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height

        Label:   # This is the first row
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]

        BoxLayout:  # This is another row (that contains two "subrows")
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            orientation: 'vertical'
            BoxLayout:  # a "subrow" of ImageButtons
            BoxLayout:  # a "subrow" of MyLabels

        FloatLayout:  # This is another row
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 150 # just an example
```

You can basically add anything you want as another "row" under the top level `BoxLayout`, but you must define the `height` of that "row" (and that generally includes setting `size_hint_y` to `None`).

Comment: Thank you! you've shed some light on the correct approach.

Comment: Is it possible to manipulate the size of individual rows using FloatLayouts inside of the BoxLayout? I want two have three consecutive rows with one height, and then a title with it's own height, then repeating..

Comment: I have added a bit more explanation in my answer above. You can add anything you want as another row under the top level `BoxLayout` as long as you define its `height`. That `height` can be whatever you want and will not affect the height of any other row. Each of the "row" `BoxLayouts` that I used in the code have their height set to `self.minimum_height`, but you can set it to anything you want.

Comment: This provided more clarification, and I can now modify each rows height, thank you for that. After more fiddling, I've basically realized that the in order to make only the button image itself clickable (rather than the entire space allocated from the boxlayout), I have to turn to FloatLayouts completely - if I have a mix of Boxlayouts and FloatLayouts, when resizing the window, everything gets misaligned. Do you have happen to have a solution for this problem without resorting to FloatLayouts? Link to the separate question I posted (too long for this comment, will post after this one)

Comment: Link here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63024668/kivy-how-do-i-restrict-the-imagebutton-click-space-to-only-on-the-image-itself